# Доступ по http (80 порт) Ubuntu, apache

Tags: linux, apache, http

Добрый день

Установил на виртуальный сервер (OS: ubuntu, VPS: amazon AWS) apache.
В iptables 80 порт открыт. Так же исходящие пакеты уходят корректно.
При попытке зайти на хост - ничего не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Информация:

Раз

```
root@ip-172-31-17-173:/var/www# nmap -sS -p 80 ya.ru

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-15 11:54 UTC
Nmap scan report for ya.ru (93.158.134.3)
Host is up (0.19s latency).
Other addresses for ya.ru (not scanned): 213.180.193.3 213.180.204.3
rDNS record for 93.158.134.3: www.yandex.ru
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.38 seconds
```

Два

```
root@ip-172-31-17-173:/var/www# netstat -anp | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN          9339/tnslsnr
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9498/apache2
```

Правила на input

```
root@ip-172-31-17-173:/var/www# iptables -L INPUT -n -v
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1521
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

Статус apache:

```
root@ip-172-31-17-173:/var/www# apachectl status
Apache Server Status for localhost (via 127.0.0.1)

Server Version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server MPM: event
Server Built: Oct 14 2015 14:20:21

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current Time: Sunday, 15-Nov-2015 12:06:15 UTC
Restart Time: Sunday, 15-Nov-2015 11:49:03 UTC
Parent Server Config. Generation: 4
Parent Server MPM Generation: 3
Server uptime: 17 minutes 11 seconds
Server load: 0.00 0.01 0.05
Total accesses: 1 - Total Traffic: 1 kB
CPU Usage: u0 s0 cu0 cs0
```

.00097 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 1024 B/request
    1 requests currently being processed, 49 idle workers

```
 PID    Connections    Threads       Async connections
      total accepting busy idle writing keep-alive closing
11716 0     yes       0    25   0       0          0
11717 0     yes       1    24   0       0          0
Sum   0               1    49   0       0          0

______________________________W___________________..............
................................................................
......................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
```

Comment: Если Вы только не используете исключительно IPv6, то смущает отсутствие IPv4 в выводе номер Два.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, открытием 80 порта на AWS.amazon (решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)

*This is actually really easy:
Go to the Security Group settings in the left hand navigation
Find the Security Group that your instance is apart of
Click on Inbound Rules
Use the drop down and add HTTP (port 80)
Click Apply and enjoy*

Answer (score 0):

Во первых в вашем netstat я вижу listen только на 80 порту протокола ipv6. на 80 порту протокола ipv4 я не вижу ничего.
Во вторых ваш ip адрес 172.31.17.173 очень странный, он из диапазона 172.16-172.32 отданного под локальные, не маршутизируемые в глобальном интернете адреса.